# Plugins missing in Firefox 4 whith dual 3.6 & 4 installed

Tags: firefox, 64-bit

I have installed both Firefox 3.6 and 4 in my 10.04 x64 ubuntu, I just downloaded the .tar.gz from the firefox page and started it up using a different firefox profile so it didn't share file between firefox versions. Now I have been unable to use the 3.6 plugins on the 4 install, I managed to install flash using flash-aid, but now I want to use the gmail voice plugin which works without problem on 3.6 but is never recognized as installed on 4.
in what folder is Firefox 4 looking for the plugins? is there an extra step to register the plugins besides creating a symbolic link to the .so file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been bugging me for months yet I solved in just minutes by myself after posting here, thanks askubuntu!

I downloaded firefox again, from the mozilla ftp to be sure that the version was 64 bits, even though that before when I went to "about:" page I saw x64 version but I'm unsure if that's the kernel or the firefox build. any ways I created a sym link like 

`ln -s /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins ~/firefox/plugins`
 and now are working both flash and google talk voice.
There are references around the web to deleting the pluginreg.dat in the firefox folder but I didn't see that in my install.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the plugin on a 32bit FF 4 installed via ppa and it works. So all you would need is a proper symlink to the plugins folder of your Firefox installation or ~/.mozilla/plugins. Are you sure you have downloaded Firefox 64bit? If you are using a 32bit browser on a 64bit system the plugins won't work. Flash works because you have used Flash-Aid, which is capable of detecting a 32bit browser on 64bit system and download the proper plugin architecture.